# Kill previous running instances, but not this current one

Tags: vb.net, winforms, process

I'm using VB.NET and I need to close (or kill) all previous runs of my
program... and only keep this most recent run.

How?   This is close... but it kills them all instead.

```
Dim thisRun As System.Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess(
Dim pList() As System.Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("MyPrg.exe")

For Each eachRun As System.Diagnostics.Process In pList
    If (Not thisRun.Equals(eachRun)) Then eachRun.Kill() ' Kill all other runs, but not this current one
Next eachRun
```

Comment: `Process.StartTime` may be just what you could use... Read more here: **https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.starttime(v=vs.110).aspx**

Comment: I would suggest start with some starter program, which will kill existing  instances and start new process.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
If (Not thisRun.Equals(eachRun)) Then eachRun.Kill()
```

try:

```
 If (Not thisRun.Id = eachRun.Id) Then eachRun.Kill()
```

The Equals operator here tries to match the Instance of the current process with other processes, which will never match in separate AppDomains untill the `.Equals` method is overridden in the Process class with a different implementation. You should match them by `Process.Id`